# Can I use a Magic Trackpad on Linux?

Tags: linux, touchpad, fedora-14, magic-trackpad

I'd like to be able to use my Magic Trackpad with Linux. While I haven't installed Linux yet to test it, the trackpad will connect to Windows on the machine (i.e. it has bluetooth). I'm going to be using Fedora 14 on a Lenovo T410.

Comment: on a side note, I got a Logitech k400+ keyboard which has an integrated trackpad. And the cons: cannot reconfigure it to have natural scrolling; it is wireless (not bluetooth) and so you need to reserve an extra usb-A slot for it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to know if they make drivers for the Magic Trackpad for Linux.  I found this discussion on [linuxforums.org](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/hardware-peripherals/167663-magic-trackpad.html). The highlights below are a little extensive, but represent the most relevant information to the question.

**Highlights**

Highlight 1

> I bought the Magic Trackpad yesterday
>   and it works fine on my macs as it
>   does on linux. Except Linux doesn't
>   support thos cool osx gestures But you
>   can use it as mouse replacement...
>
> In Ubuntu Karmic (10.04) e.g. you just
>   need to get kernel 2.6.35 - which is
>   available from the ppa:kernel/ppa
>   repo. One reboot and one bt pairing
>   later it works...left/right click and
>   point and click (the last one only
>   using the integrated button). In
>   Ubuntu 10.10 it works from the scratch
>   hence 10.10 alrady includes 2.6.35 or
>   newer kernel...
>
> Have fun with it...

Highlight 2

> You will only be able to get a maximum
>   of up to 2 finger up/down scrolling on
>   Linux with the magic trackpad.
>   Pinch-to-rotate, 3-finger and 4 finger
>   scrolling won't work.
>   which makes it as good as an expensive
>   paperweight.

Highlight 3

> Multitouch support is said to come
>   with ubuntu Maverick (10.10)... Also
>   Firefox and Chrome are reported to
>   work on Multitouch Support to come
>   soon. Still I like the fact that I can
>   use the trackpad on my macs as well as
>   on my linux boxes

Comment: what's the status now in 2018? can anyone give an update? will be real helpful. :)

Comment: After Googling "Can I use a Magic Trackpad on Linux", the first result is as follows:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad
From that article, it identifies that it does work with Ubuntu, which is a flavor of Linux. If you would like to know if it works with your flavor of Linux, I would recommend putting that in your search criteria instead of "Linux".

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned that. But yes, that was the first result. However, the latest Ubuntu shown is 12.04 LTS. I wonder how it is for 16.04 LTS. Maybe it is the same, and therefore they have not updated the wiki documentation?

Comment: After Googling "Can I use a Magic Trackpad on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS," the first result was as follows (Google is your friend):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/133970/apple-magic-trackpad-aftrer-upgrade-from-ubuntu-11-10-to-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit
In this article, someone has issues with using the Magic Trackpad, which are fixed by installing utouch with the following command: apt-get install utouch

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I Googled the wrong thing. Re-reading your post where you identify the version, I see that you are asking about 16.04 LTS. I found the following site that has a driver for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: https://github.com/robotrovsky/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver

Comment: I'm using one on Ubuntu 17.10. It's not ideal. Gestures could apparently be added (but I haven't bothered). It's nowhere as smooth as on macOS (in fact, it's rather choppy in the movements and hard to do precision things). It keeps disconnecting every ~10 min for 5-10s, which is insanely annoying. Two finger scroll works fine.

Comment: @vpetersson, is that with the latest drivers from the URL mentioned in my comment from Jan 15 at 18:44?

Comment: @David - no that's for Magic Trackpad 2 - I have the first version, so no mods at all.

Comment: @vpetersson, nice observation. That is my ignorance on the topic. I was thinking it was a 2.0 revision of the driver.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the important text. The website linuxforums.org is down (may 2021)